# Canvas how to handle my canvas when it start on center screen

Tags: javascript, canvas

[image: Here is my canvas(blue border) and my shape is green]

The canvas is in the center of the screen and when I add event click and call console.log(e.clientX, e.client.Y) it give e.g. 530, 483 but my shape is 50,50 from canvas.

how do i know i've click on shape not the canvas on the background.

```
let shapes:any = [];
shapes.push({ x:50, y:50, width: this.qrSize, height: this.qrSize, color:'lightgreen' })

let is_mouse_in_shape = function(x:any, y:any, shape:any){
  let shape_left = shape.x;
  let shape_right = shape.x + shape.width;
  let shape_top = shape.y;
  let shape_bottom = shape.y + shape.height;
  console.log(x,y)        // x = 415, y = 467
  console.log(shape_left, shape_top)         // x = 50, y = 50
  if( x > shape_left && x < shape_right && y > shape_top && y > shape_bottom ){
    return true;
  }
  return false; // It's return false
}
let mouse_down = function(event:any){
  event.preventDefault();
  startX = parseInt(event.clientX);
  startY = parseInt(event.clientY);
  console.log(event)
  let index = 0;
  for(let shape of shapes){
    if(is_mouse_in_shape(startX, startY, shape)){
      console.log('yes');
      current_shape_index = index;
    } else {
      console.log('no')
    }
    index++;
  }
}
let draw_shapes = function(){
  context.clearRect(0,0, canvas_width, canvas_height);
  for (let shape of shapes){
    context.fillStyle = shape.color;
    context.fillRect(shape.x, shape.y, shape.width, shape.height);
  }
}
draw_shapes();
canvas.onmousedown = mouse_down;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.clientX` and `clientY` give you the click position relative to the top-left of the window.

To get the click position relative to the top-left of the canvas, you have to subtract the canvas offset from it.

To do so, you can use `canvas.getBoundingClientRect`. You subtract its `left` value from `clientX`, and `top` from `clientY` before passing to the `is_mouse_in_shape` check.

Here's a working example. Note: I had to fix a small typo in the collision detection: `y > shape_bottom` should be `y < shape_bottom`.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
const canvas_width = canvas.width;
const canvas_height = canvas.height;

let shapes = [];
shapes.push({ x:50, y:50, width: 30, height: 30, color:'lightgreen' })

let is_mouse_in_shape = function(x, y, shape){
  let shape_left = shape.x;
  let shape_right = shape.x + shape.width;
  let shape_top = shape.y;
  let shape_bottom = shape.y + shape.height;
  console.log(x,y)        // x = 415, y = 467
  console.log(shape_left, shape_top)         // x = 50, y = 50
  if( x > shape_left && x < shape_right && y > shape_top && y < shape_bottom ){
    return true;
  }
  return false; // It's return false
}
let mouse_down = function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  const { left, top } = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  startX = parseInt(event.clientX) - left;
  startY = parseInt(event.clientY) - top;
  
  
  let index = 0;
  for(let shape of shapes){
    if(is_mouse_in_shape(startX, startY, shape)){
      console.log('yes');
      current_shape_index = index;
    } else {
      console.log('no')
    }
    index++;
  }
}
let draw_shapes = function(){
  context.clearRect(0,0, canvas_width, canvas_height);
  for (let shape of shapes){
    context.fillStyle = shape.color;
    context.fillRect(shape.x, shape.y, shape.width, shape.height);
  }
}

draw_shapes();
canvas.onmousedown = mouse_down;
```

```css
canvas {
  margin-top: 23px;
  margin-left: 123px;
  border: 2px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: I've a few more question, Is it right if I run this in mounted. I'm using vueJS.